# Eclipse no reconoce Entity ni javax.persistence.Entity

Tags: maven

Cuando escribo @Entity arriba de la declaración de mi clase Java, no me aparece la opción de importarlo. Escribí "import javax.persistence.Entity;" por mi cuenta y tampoco lo reconoce. Había instalado estas dependencias Maven&Hibernate. Después click derecho en pom.xml, run as maven install. Después maven->maven update pero el error seguía. Ahora cuando hago Maven build o install me sale esto:

```
[ERROR] Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
[ERROR] Target option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
... [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.learning.linkedin</groupId>
  <artifactId>otrareunionmas</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>otrareunionmas</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

  <dependencies>
  
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.33</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-agroal</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sabias que en las nuevas versiones de java se cambio el paquete `javax` por `jakarta`? Porque no pruebas con `import jakarta.persistence.Entity;` [Al principio se decía que no iba a haber afectaciones](https://jarrambide.com/java/porque-cambia-de-nombre-java-ee-a-jakarta-ee/) pero después, si se cambio el nombre del paquete mencionado.